# Image is not shown in JavaFX ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to show an image in an ImageView in JavaFX. The image should be fetched from the SQLite Database and shown when the scene loads. I use the following code snippet to fetch the code from the database and to show it in previously created ImageView. But the Image is not shown as expected. Am I doing it wrong?
p.s. I have tested changing the path in both `FileOutputStream` and when reading the file from the directory to `src/image.jpg`. But nothing seems to work. But when I put an image file manually in the src directory and try to read it, it works like a charm. But I want to show an image fetched from the database.

```
@FXML
private void loadEquipmentData() throws IOException {
    try{
        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement checkStmt = conn.prepareStatement(selectEquipmentQuery);
        ResultSet rs = checkStmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("Image");
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("image.jpg"));
            byte[] content = new byte[1024];
            int size = 0;
            while ((size = is.read(content)) != -1){
                os.write(content, 0, size);
            }
            os.close();
            is.close();

            File file = new File("file:image.jpg");
            image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            this.eq_img.setImage(image);
            this.eq_img.setPreserveRatio(true);
            this.eq_img.setFitWidth(318.0);
            this.eq_img.setFitHeight(253.0);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        fnf.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When writing the image to database I use this code to choose image.

```
private FileChooser fileChooser;
private File file;
private FileInputStream fis;

@FXML
void chooseFiles() throws FileNotFoundException {
    CommonStageSingleton stageSingleton = CommonStageSingleton.getInstance();
    Stage userStage = stageSingleton.getMainWindow();
    fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files","*.jpg","*gif","*.jpeg","*.png")
    );

    file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(userStage);
    if(file != null){
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ta_imagePath.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

And these to enter it to database.

```
Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement checkStmt = conn.prepareStatement(checkEquipmentQuery);
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(insertEquipmentQuery);
st.setBinaryStream(12, (InputStream)fis, (int)file.length());
```

I might have done something to save this image not as a `.jpg`.

Comment: Maybe try `new File("image.jpg")`nor the same `File` object

Comment: First of all: What do you mean by "But the Image is not shown as expected."?
Secondly: Is this a plain java project, or are build tools (like maven/gradle) used?
Else: Is `file.toURI()` as expected?

Comment: @gkhaos Sorry for not being clear. Even I set the image in ImageView, it does not appear. And I did not use any build tool such as maven or gradle. I am a beginner to JavaFX and what I did was create a JavaFX project in IntelliJ Community. I don't think that method is going to use any build tool.

Comment: @dan1st Thank you for your suggestion. But it did not work.

Comment: Is the file being created? Can you display this created file using your OS?

Comment: @dan1st Oops! That file is created. but it cannot be opened using my OS. It gives me `Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x52 0x49)`.

Comment: Or just create the image from the binary stream you receive from the DB without using a file

Comment: Can you confirm, that the image in the database is ok? And that the downloaded file is not corrupted or anything? Maybe check on `file.toURI()` and see the `.jpg` file in an image viewer...
Copying a file into the `src/` folder results in the file being copied to the build folder. (the image from the database should be there too)

Comment: @dan1st But that file can be open inside intelliJ.

Comment: Is there a JPG image in the DB or something else?

Comment: @gkhaos Created image cannot be open via my OS's Image Viewer Software, but it can be open within intelliJ.

Comment: Look at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). 0x52 means RNC or RAR or WAVE or WEBP

Comment: Can you show the first parts from the image in a hex editor?

Comment: @dan1st I edited my question with "how i choose and put that image in the database". Can you tell me if I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217198/discussion-between-rangana-udara-and-dan1st).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dan1st pointed out what I am missing here. I have used webp image as the input image when writing into the database. JavaFX does not support webp image type. Now I use jpeg and that gives no any issue sofar.